# Store multiple CSS classes in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays

I'm still pretty new to JQuery and JavaScript as a whole, so bear with me. I tried searching the web for an answer to my question and experimented a little bit, but I'm coming up dry. Anyway, is there a way to **store multiple CSS classes in an array** with JavaScript?

I'm writing some simple JQuery for a friend's portfolio website such as this:

```
$('.item.two').click(function(){
    $('.content.item, .current.item').show();
    $('.content.item, .content.item, .content.item, .current.item, .current.item, .current.item').hide();
    $('.item.one, .item.three, .item.four').fadeTo(0, 0.5);
    $('.item.two').fadeTo(0, 1.0);
});
```

All this is doing is hiding certain elements and only showing them when their corresponding icon is clicked on. This is also turning the opacity from 50% off the main class to 100% when clicked on.

There's nothing wrong with the code itself, it serves its intended purpose. But is there a way to clean this code up a bit by just holding those classes into a reusable array? I feel like it should be possible, but I'm not sure how.

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Sorry, I wasn't clear that I'm actually using 4 different classes to hide or show. So instead of the previous bit it's actually

```
$('.item.two').click(function(){
    // this is the content i want to show on click
    $('.content.itemTwo').show();
    // this is the content that i want to hide/remain hiding on click
    $('.content.itemOne, .content.itemThree, .content.itemFour').hide();

    // these are icons representing the content
    $('.item.one, .item.three, .item.four').fadeTo(0, 0.5);
    $('.item.two').fadeTo(0, 1.0);
});
```

Also, here is my HTML some of you are requesting. Like I said, what I'm trying to make happen, happens. I just feel like there's a better way of making it happen.

```
<!-- these are icons representing the written content-->
<div class="item one">
    <div class="fs1" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe000;"></div>
</div>
<div class="item two">
    <div class="fs1" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe003;"></div>
</div>
<div class="item three">
    <div class="fs1" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe001;"></div>
</div>
<div class="item four">
    <div class="fs1" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe002;"></div>
</div>

<!-- this is the written content to be shown upon clicking corresponding icon -->
<div class="content itemOne">
    <h3>itemOne</h3>
    <p>....</p>
</div>
<div class="content itemTwo">
    <h3>itemTwo</h3>
    <p>...</p>
<div class="content itemThree">
    <h3>itemThree</h3>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
<div class="content itemFour">
    <h3>itemFour</h3>
    <p>....</p>
</div>
```

Looking at it now, I probably don't need the extra selectors on the .content or .item.

Comment: It looks like you're not getting it, you don't have to type the same class four times inside the selector, once is enough. Show us the HTML, and we'll try to show you a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood , you are trying to change the element that is clicked.

```
 $('.item.two').click(function(){
    // there is no reason to show and then hide all
    $('.content.item, .current.item').hide();
    $('.item').not(this).fadeTo(0, 0.5);
    $(this).fadeTo(0, 1.0);
});
```

check if this works for you

Edit another approch could be using index suffix in classes in loop 
eg

you could use class1, class2, class3 instead.

```
$('.item.two').click(function(){
    // this is the content i want to show on click
    $('.content.itemTwo').show();
    // this is the content that i want to hide/remain hiding on click
    $('.content.itemOne, .content.itemThree, .content.itemFour').hide();

    // these are icons representing the content
    $('.item.one, .item.three, .item.four').fadeTo(0, 0.5);
    $('.item.two').fadeTo(0, 1.0);
});
```

to

```
for(var i=1;i<=4;i++){
  $('.item.'+i).click(function(){
        // this is the content i want to show on click
        $('.content.class'+i).show();
        // this is the content that i want to hide/remain hiding on click
        $('.content class').hide();

        // these are icons representing the content
        $('.item').not(this).fadeTo(0, 0.5);
        $(this).fadeTo(0, 1.0);
    });

}
```

Hope you can get approch from it

Comment: no need to supply `$(this)`, just need to supply `this`, as the select created within `.not()` will be parsed as a jQuery object; and thussly causes an unnecessary redundancy. Also, what if `.content` and `.current` will be targeted by `$('.item')`. if that's the case, you would have to chain the `.not()`, such as `.not(this).not('.current, .content')`

Comment: I was not knowing about $(this) redundancy.thanks for that, secondly ... code given is initself ambiguous I am waiting for the asker to reply and then can change accordingly

Comment: I am in 100% agreeance regarding the ambiguity of the question and the supplied code considering the possible scenarios. I would have created the same exact answer, but would've just supplied the part about excluding the other selectors. Also, maybe a piece of information about the redundancy of the selectors on the 2nd line, and how the first line is cancelled about by the 2nd line. +1 none the less.

Comment: Sorry if I'm unclear guys, I'm just trying to learn some new stuff. I'll try and be less ambiguous with my questions in the future. I'll give these a shot and report back tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `push` method like

```
var arrayClass = [];
$('.item.two').click(function() { 
   arrayClass.push($(this));
});

alert(arrayClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to repeat same class over and over and do not need to store classes in array.

*Change*

```
 $('.content.item, .content.item, .content.item, .current.item, .current.item, .current.item').hide();
```

*To*

```
 $('.content.item').hide();
```

You can store classes in `string` instead of `array` in this case  `$('.item.one, .item.three, .item.four')`

```
classesSet = ".item.one, .item.three, .item.four";
$(strClassesSet).fadeTo(0, 0.5);
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually using unique classes for each thing I'm hiding/showing. Should have been more clear. I have a main .content class in my CSS and each .item has something a tiny bit different from the last, so I end up doing something like <div class="content itemOne"></div> and so forth until itemFour. So it's not really all <div class="content item"></div>

Comment: You can store them in string then, showing your html could make it more clear, if you can make your class names to be used with wild card then you can use attribute selector.

Comment: Great, I'll look more into this. So far it's working fine for me, I'm just having trouble accessing the different parts of data in the string. I'll go and do some more research, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You mean you are trying to select a list of items using jQuery because you have been using a lot of clases? You can do this by using jquery index, with eq and the this selector. 
Here is a full description on how to use the index feature to make your code shorter
http://api.jquery.com/index/